# Boxing/Unboxing complex types in Julia

Tags: c, scripting, julia, ffi

I have basically digged through all Julia documentation, but I cannot find any answers on this. My question can be split into two parts. Code snippets ignore stuff like basic s initialization.

## Part 1: How to pass basic complex types without `jl_eval_string()`

Suppose I have a C/C++ program which calls some Julia scripts, for a function `f` which do some `String` manipulation. In the C source:

```
char* parameter_string; // Initialized as something.
jl_module_t *m = (jl_module_t *) jl_load("Script.jl");
jl_function_t *f = jl_get_function(m, "f");
jl_value_t * ret = jl_call1(f, /*???*/) <--- Problem
```

Now, notice that the manual only describes how to box up primitives, like int, float, double. Nothing about complex types, like `String`. Yes, I can use `jl_eval_string(parameter_string)`, but I don't like this. Moreover, `ret` will be a String, and I have no idea how to extract it to C. It is undocumented.

## Part 2:

Suppose I have a C/C++ program which calls some Julia scripts, in which a state machine is stepped. To create a state machine, I create some types:

```
abstract State
type Idle <: State end
type State1 <: State end
type State2 <: State end
```

And then a transition function:

```
function transition(s :: State, input :: String) # input :: String is arbitrary
  .. Do Something ..
  return newState
end
```

Now, if I want to create a `State`, say `Idle`, in C... I cannot find anything like this, let alone finding a way to retrieve it from Julia.

I am approaching this problem more or less like functional programming language, such as Haskell, Scala, or F#. Algebraic Data Type might not be well supported here, but I think it is still better than hard coding it with integers.

The real problem is that I cannot find any C API documents on Julia, without directly digging into its source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a C string to a Julia `String` using `jl_cstr_to_string(char*)`.

To get the data from a Julia `String`, use `jl_string_ptr(jl_value_t*)`.

Constructors are called just like functions, so to call a constructor you can use `jl_get_function(m, "Idle")` and call it as normal. Or, to allocate an object directly (going around any constructors that might be defined, so technically a bit dangerous), you can call `jl_new_struct(type, fields...)`.

Comment: OK, I see. BTW, I am not that familiar with Julia's type system, so I am not sure whether that ADT-like structure will actually work

Comment: And what about retrieving? Is it something like `ret->type`? Or is it `jl_valueof()` and `jl_typeof()`? They are macros so I don't really know their type

Comment: Yes, you can get the type of a `jl_value_t*` using `jl_typeof()`. The `jl_value_t*` itself already points to the data area (after the type tag).

Comment: What do I get if I use `jl_valueof()` on a complex type? Or, is it what `jl_get_nth_field()` or `jl_get_field()` for? (Yeah, browsing 1800+ lines of code to guess API is not really fun...)

Comment: If you want to access fields of a composite value, yes you want `jl_get_nth_field` or `jl_get_field`. I agree the embedding docs need to cover a lot more, but I'm not sure what `jl_get_field` would do other than get a field. `jl_get_nth_field` is faster since it avoids looking up the index for the field name.